# It is possible to approve the openid certification for wso2 is?

Tags: wso2, openid, wso2-identity-server

The certification openid is this http://openid.net/certification/ and i don't know if it is posible pass with wso2 is.

In the next link talk about wso2 is but does not specify specify it is approvove

http://openid.net/developers/uncertified/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming

Comment: this is a important question

Answer (score 0):

From IS 5.2.0,  it is compliance  with OIDC basic and implicit profiles but not hybrid, config and dynamic profiles.  In our road maps we have tracked the requirement to compliance the other pofiles as well.  In future releases this will be added.